# Cant's save image with awssum and nodejs to amazon S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

My node js code opens a local png file from my server, tmp.png, and then tries to save it amazon S3. I keep running into problems and I suspect it has something to do with the encoding. The only way it work is with base64 encoding (which I don't want for my photos).

```
fs = require('fs');
var awssum = require('awssum');
var amazon = awssum.load('amazon/amazon');
var s3Service = awssum.load('amazon/s3');

var s3 = new s3Service('mykey', 'mysecret', 'account', amazon.US_WEST_1);

fs.readFile('./tmp.png', function (err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log("There was an error opening the file");
    } else {
        s3.PutObject({
            BucketName : 'my-bucket',
            ObjectName : 'tmp.png',
            ContentType : 'image/png',
            ContentLength : data.length,
            Body          : data,
        }, function(err, data) {
            if(err){
                console.log("There was an error writing the data to S3:");
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Your data has been written to S3:");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Obviously my-bucket is actually my unique bucket name. The message I get back from amazon is a request timeout:

> Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed.

Comment: Note, this code is using an older version of AwsSum (my library) from about v0.4. The newer versions v0.5 and above have slightly different syntax so it's worth looking at the examples/ folder that comes with AwsSum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a found an example in the docs that does what I need it to. The key was to use fs.stat for the file size and fs.createReadStream to read in the file:

```
// you must run fs.stat to get the file size for the content-length header (s3 requires this)
fs.stat(path, function(err, file_info) {
    if (err) {
        inspect(err, 'Error reading file');
        return;
    }

    var bodyStream = fs.createReadStream( path );

    console.log(file_info.size);

    var options = {
        BucketName    : 'my-bucket',
        ObjectName    : 'test.png',
        ContentType   : 'image/png',
        ContentLength : file_info.size,
        Body          : bodyStream
    };

    s3.PutObject(options, function(err, data) {
        console.log("\nputting an object to my-bucket - expecting success");
        inspect(err, 'Error');
        inspect(data, 'Data');
    });
});
```

Comment: Even above code does not work for me. I still get Request Timeout error. Any idea?